# access hierarchy between php and httpd

Tags: php, http

The objective is to control access to a php/httpd app, owncloud, to specific identified ip addresses. Both php and httpd appear to have mechanisms to do this, php is through a config.php file with trusted domain construct:

```
'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'localhost',
    1 => '10.0.0.0/16',
    2 => 'aa.bb.cc.dd',
  ),
```

and http is through owncloud.conf in the conf.d directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/http/owncloud/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride none
     Order Allow, Deny
     Deny from all
     Allow from 10.0.0.0/16
     Allow from aa.bb.cc.dd
</Directory>
```

What are the roles of these? Are they serial or mutually exclusive? In order to limit php access is necessary to change the config.php configuration? Is there a way to limit php access through httpd.conf? Does that question even make sense?

Comment: How did you edit the text to create the shadowed area. I tried list but that was not correct.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

- Limiting the access on the side of Apache is a more general approach that works for everything, including static files. It's a generally more secure approach because the request is blocked before the PHP interpreter ever sees it, making it impossible (or at least much more difficult) to exploit bugs in the PHP app.
- Limiting the access on the side of a PHP application only works for  that PHP application and is far more limited in scope. Without additional configuration on the Apache server side, you can't prevent  access to anything not under the control of the PHP application, e.g. static images or other resources. It also doesn't prevent a request from reaching the PHP interpreter in the first place, leaving it susceptible to attempts to exploit bugs in the software. Also, in many web applications, this kind of access control isn't present to begin because the system wants to rely on the web server for this purpose.

In short: In cases where the Apache access control is usable, I would always prefer this over access control offered by a PHP application.

Answer (score -1):

First is the Apache ACL, then the PHP one. You cannot include in PHP what you excluded in Apache before.